# Where to put the hasOne and the foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I'm currently learning the development with `Laravel` and I'm encountering a little problem. I would like to have two `Models`: `Users` and `Addresses`

A User has one `Address`, so I have to put the `foreign key` for the `address` in the `user` table right? But according to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), it's the `Address` table to have the `user foreign key`.

> Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method:

How should I work to have the `foreign key` in the `User` table and not in the `Address` table (which is way more logic in my opinion). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more correct to have the `user_id` field in the address table.  But if you want to do it this way, use a `belongsTo` relationship instead:

```
class User {

    public function address(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');

    }

}
```

You can see from the language that this isn't right - A user should have one address, and an address should belong to a user.  But this code will work if you prefer this way.

Comment: I would like to do it this way because my address entity will be used for an "event" entity which will also have an address.

Answer (score 1):

You can put in the address query within the Users model.

```
public function address(){

    return  $this-> hasOne(\App\Address::class);

}
```

Then can call like:

```
 {{$this->user->address()}}
```

Thane within your Address table make a field called users_id for the above to use.

Comment: `belongsTo` does not use a pivot table